# Deserializing avro message in kdb

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, kdb

I am working on a problem which requires me to consume avro serialized messages from kafka topics in kdb+ service. Is it possible to deserialize avro messages in kdb?

Comment: Unless kdb has a Kafka consumer itself, I suggest you use Kafka Connect to handle deserialization, then upload those records to your system

Comment: From github, kdb uses something called kfk, which is built on librdkafka... So, see https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka/issues/2523

Comment: @OneCricketeer thanks for your response I am using librdkafka to interface with kafka. But it doesn't have support to parse avro message out of the box. edenhill's response is to use another library which is not be possible in my case.

Comment: That's the only way to support non standard serialization formats, using librdkafka, unfortunately, unless you have other ways to generate byte arrays

Comment: Ajay Rathore wrote a library which you might be able to use, see https://github.com/ajayrathore/krak